# "$injector:unpr Unknown provider" after adding resolve in $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs

I searched already for similar problems but couldn't figure out what the problem is in my specific case. Maybe one of you has an idea?

My code was executing with out an error but I had to add `resolve` to my `$stateProvider`. After doing so I got following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: rquoteShipmentListProvider <- rquoteShipmentList <- vendorQuoteCtrl http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=rquoteShipmentListProvider%20%3C-%20rquoteShipmentList%20%3C-%20vendorQuoteCtrl at Anonymous function (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js:4289:13) ...
```

My code:

```
var app = angular.module("offerModul", ["ui.router", "ui.bootstrap"]); 

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
    .state("main",{
        url: "/",
        controller:'vendorQuoteCtrl',
        templateUrl:'src/html/vendorQuoteRequest.html',
        resolve: {
            rquoteShipmentList: function(shipmentService) {
                return shipmentService.loadquoteShipments();
            }
        }
    });
});

app.controller('vendorQuoteCtrl', ['$scope', 'shipmentService', 'carrierService', 'chargesService', 'rquoteShipmentList', function($scope, shipmentService, carrierService, chargesService, rquoteShipmentList) {
    $scope.quoteShipmentList = rquoteShipmentList;

    $scope.open = function ()
    {
        init();
    }

    function init() {
        $scope.quoteShipmentList = shipmentService.getquoteShipments();
    }
}]);

app.service('shipmentService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var quoteShipmentList = null;

    return {
        loadquoteShipments: function () {
            $http.get("./src/data/getShipments.php",{
                cache: true})
                .success(function (response) { quoteShipmentList = response; alert("quoteShipmentList:" + quoteShipmentList);})
                .error(function (data, status) {
                    alert("error getting Quotes! status:"+status);
            });
            alert("should be set:" + quoteShipmentList);
            return quoteShipmentList;
        },
        getquoteShipments: function () {
            return quoteShipmentList;

        }
    };

}]);
```

Before adding `resolve` my code is executed without an error. The code before:

```
var app = angular.module("offerModul", ["ui.router", "ui.bootstrap"]); 

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
    .state("main",{
        url: "/",
        controller:'vendorQuoteCtrl',
        templateUrl:'src/html/vendorQuoteRequest.html'
    });
});

app.controller('vendorQuoteCtrl', ['$scope', 'shipmentService', 'carrierService', 'chargesService', function($scope, shipmentService, carrierService, chargesService) {
    $scope.quoteShipmentList = shipmentService.loadquoteShipments();

    $scope.open = function ()
    {
        init();
    }

    function init() {
        $scope.quoteShipmentList = shipmentService.getquoteShipments();
    }
}]);

app.service('shipmentService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var quoteShipmentList = null;
    var shipmentList = null;

    return {
        loadquoteShipments: function () {
            $http.get("./src/data/getShipments.php",{
                cache: true})
                .success(function (response) { quoteShipmentList = response; alert("quoteShipmentList:" + quoteShipmentList);})
                .error(function (data, status) {
                    alert("error getting Quotes! status:"+status);
            });
            alert("should be set:" + quoteShipmentList);
            return quoteShipmentList;
        },
        getquoteShipments: function () {
            return quoteShipmentList;

        }
    };

}]);
```

Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Like recommended in other posts I deleted `ng-controller` from my html BUT I didn't saw that there was another one in a modal-dialog (?:-/). 
Removing that tag removed the error!
Thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem in the resolve. you have to inject your service shipmentService in the resolve  like we inject in controller.

Something like :

```
resolve: {     
    rquoteShipmentList: ['rquoteShipmentList', function (rquoteShipmentList){
        return shipmentService.loadquoteShipments();
    }],
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer.  You rather mean "rquoteShipmentList: ['shipmentService', function (shiopmentService){...", right? I've tried it but I got the same error :-(